# ACF render wysiwyg post type value as html file

Tags: html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a whole HTML code inserted in a wysiwyg post type. I want to create an endpoint that render this post type as html page.

Sample acf url:  `{{site}}/wp-json/wp/v2/post_type/?_fields=acf.html_contents`

By default this returns:

```
  "acf": {
    "html_contents": "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><head><body>><p>Hello</p></body></html>
   }
```

So far I got this added in functions.php:

```
     add_filter('acf/rest/format_value_for_rest/type=wysiwyg', 
          function ($value_formatted, $post_id, $field, $value, $format) {  
              Header('Content-Type: text/html');
              echo $value;
              // return the overridden value
     }, 10, 5);
```

However this returns an error of:

```
     Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by 
        wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php on line 1762
```